# Is it possible to fix this? Clear coat turned out matte looking

Tags: paint, body-work, body, paint-clearcoat

I applied 4 coats of clear, waiting 10 minutes in between, but it came out matte looking and it is not smooth. Is it possible to fix this?

[image]

Comment: This has been asked on here before. Short answer humidity and so many other factors are at play...

Comment: @SolarMike so is it possible to fix this, if so, how?

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/77635/10976

Comment: Or this, https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/31570/10976

Comment: How does it feel to the touch? Trying to get an idea how much of the dullness is down to humidity and how much is down to the texture of the finish.

Comment: @motosubatsu it feels a little rough

Comment: Hmm.. yeah it did look it. Without seeing it in the metal to be sure that *might* be the root cause (it doesn't have quite the milkiness I'd expect if it was down to pure humidity), I'd say it's worth a go to wet sand (probably ~1200 grit) try machine polishing up with a gentle cutting compound.

Comment: @motosubatsu should I wet sand with 1200 alone or try 2000 afterwards?

Comment: Sort of depends how it feels after the 1200, if it is dull but **smooth** you can go straight to mop-ing and work through a couple of the gentler compounds, but if it's still a little rough a follow up with 2000 isn't a bad idea before moving on to the polish/buff.

Comment: On the other hand if it still feels really rough after the 1200 it might be time to roll up the sleeves and get the 600 out - in which case you'd probably go 600->15000->polisher

Comment: @motosubatsu thanks for the tip, although I know very little about polishing, what compound should I choose after wet sanding? There are so many different things, is polishing paste the same thing as a scratch remover?

Comment: What you're looking for is something often called a "cutting compound" - many manufacturers will grade them in effectively a "grit" like sand paper is, and the principle is the same as with sanding, start with a lower grit and move up to a higher one for finishing.

Comment: If you haven't got a suitable machine polisher you'll need to look for something that can be applied by hand [Megs Ultimate Compound](https://www.polishedbliss.co.uk/meguiars-ultimate-compound) is a great one for novices, although it might be lacking in outright cutting power for this job, although you could compensate with an additional wet sand with a super high grit (say 2500-3000) if required. It's a great all-in-one since you generally don't need a separate finishing polish step.

Comment: @motosubatsu, thanks a lot for the help, I'm gonna go to a professional body shop tomorrow and see what they have to say

Comment: @motosubatsu well damn... they tried wet sanding and polishing and the clear coat is just peeling off, they're going to repaint it, fortunately, it's just 120 euros

Comment: Peeling off? Did you let the clear coat cure a couple a days? Or a least a week and then try wet sanding?